# Uploading a File with Ajax POST, Multipart content and JSON payload

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, multipartform-data

There is a REST service, which enables me to upload a file. I have to construct a POST request with the following payload, for example:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary= ---1234567890
-----1234567890
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="parameters"
Content-Type: application/json

{
"parentID":"FB4CD874EF94CD2CC1B60B72T0000000000100000001"
}
-----1234567890
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="primaryFile"; filename="example.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

<File Content>
-----1234567890--
```

Looks simple enough. The first part is a JSON object, that decribes the location on the server, where the file should be saved, the second part is the file itself. (Please note that I am n no position to modify the server.)

After lots of googling, I discovered that I can use FormData object to create this multipart request. Here is my code:

```
function checkInNewFile(folderId, file)
{
  var response;
  var fd = new FormData();

  var parent = new Blob(['{ "parentID": "' + folderId + '" }"'], { type: "application/json"});
  fd.append("parameters", parent, null);

  fd.append("primaryFile", file);

  var jqXHR =
    $.ajax(
      {
        type: "POST",
        url: someURL,
        async: false,

        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
      }
    );
  jqXHR.done( function (data) { response = data; });
  return response;
}
```

The generated request is almost the expected one ... the file content is correct, but I am unable to create exactly the first part. Actually the code above produce this first part:

```
-----1234567890
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="parameters"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/json

{
"parentID":"FB4CD874EF94CD2CC1B60B72T0000000000100000001"
}
```

As you see, there is an additional filename attribute in the request, and although the actual name is empty, my server does not like the request in this form.

Of course I tried to add a simple text value as the first part:

```
  var parent = '{ "parentID" : "' +  folderId + '" }';
  fd.append("parameters", parent);
```

but now the request looks like:

```
-----1234567890
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="parameters"

{ "parentID":"FB4CD874EF94CD2CC1B60B72T0000000000100000001" }
```

i.e. the Content-Type is missing, and it is not accepted by the server.

I was trying to add the data as an object, but it did not help at all, either the Content-type or the actual JSON representation, or both were missing.

Reading the FormData documentation, I did not find any other choice. And I do not know enough JavaScript to rewrite FormData from scratch.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm having a little difficulty following your code. Wouldn't the AJAX request never get reached because you're executing a `return` before it (in this line: `return postFile(CHECKIN_NEW_FILE, folderId, fd);`)? I might be missing something with this question though...

Comment: Hi @lewiguez! I am sorry, you are right! I wanted to simplify the code, so I inlined the body of the function postFile, without removing the call. Corrected the source above.